# Unity VR game being blurry/shaky on Oculus Rift

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, 360-virtual-reality

I have a problem with my VR project in Unity, where the Raycast and the tooltips from my UI Canvas appear blurry and shaky, and the overall project looks more blurry than in the Oculus Menu outside my application for example.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

[Here is a picture that show my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiIoR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a result of TimeWarp, a mechanism oculus is using to interpolate intermediate frames to achieve target frame rate in cases when the application is not pushing out enough frames per second

tl;dr this is a performance problem